# Iterate Complex JSON Object of Unknown complexity

Tags: javascript, html, json, recursion, iteration

This should be an easy problem, but for some reason, I'm hitting a brick wall.

I have a JSON object of unknown complexity, which may contain other objects, arrays or string properties.

As an example, I may have an object like this:

```js
let json = {
    id: "foo",
    rows: [
        {
            class: "blah",
            cols: [
                {
                    class: "haha"
                },{
                    class: "bar"
                },{
                    class: "baz"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            class: "yada"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Note (for clarity): The object may have a widely differing structure. It may have rows and cols reversed, or be nested deeper, or not at all.  There may or may not be be ids or classes on any of the objects *

I need to iterate over that object and "transform" it into an html structure, like this:

```html
<div id = "foo" data-type = "rows">
    <div class = "blah" data-type = "cols">
        <div class = "haha"></div>
        <div class = "bar"></div>
        <div class = "baz"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "yada"></div>
</div>
```

where each object is a (perhaps nested) div and the string properties are attributes on that div and the array keys indicate a type.

Here's what I've got presently:

```js
function iterateJsonToHTML(frame)  {
    let content = document.createElement("div");
     let iterator = function(frame, content)  {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(frame))  {
            if (Array.isArray(value)  ||  (typeof value === "object"  &&  value !== null) )  {
                if (Array.isArray(value))  {
                    iterator(value, content);
                }  else if (typeof value === "object")  {
                    let element = document.createElement("div");
                    content = content.appendChild(element);
                     iterator(value, content);
                }
            }  else {
                // dealing with attributes here.  Not sure how to parse multiple of these.
            }
        }
    };
    iterator(frame, content);
    return content;
}
```

This creates an HTML structure, just not the one I'm expecting:

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's got the right number of `div`s, they're just pivoted somehow.

So my question is simple:

Where am I going wrong in my recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original snippet can be easily made to work - the child elements in your input format are stored as arrays so you just need to iterate over them before creating the child divs:

```js
function iterateJsonToHTML(frame)  {
    let root = document.createElement("div");
    let iterator = function(frame, content)  {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(frame))  {
            if (Array.isArray(value))  {
                content.setAttribute("data-type", key);
                for (let item of value) {
                    const element = document.createElement("div");
                    content.appendChild(element);
                    iterator(item, element);
                }
            }  else {
                content.setAttribute(key, value);
            }
        }
    };
    iterator(frame, root);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Awesome... Thanks... I see now where my mistake was.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this very simple one-line function `render`

*Note: If you want the div properties(id, class, data-type) in the same line, is just put all the first validations on the same line*

```js
const obj = {
    id: "foo",
    rows: [
        {
            class: "blah",
            cols: [
                {
                    class: "haha"
                },{
                    class: "bar"
                },{
                    class: "baz"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            class: "yada"
        }
    ]
}
const render = (obj) =>  
  `
    <div 
      ${ obj.class ? `class="${obj.class}"` : '' }
      ${ obj.id ? `id="${obj.id}"` : '' }
      ${ obj.rows 
          ? 'data-type="rows"' 
          : obj.cols 
            ? 'data-type="cols"' 
            : '' }
    >
      ${
        (obj.cols || obj.rows || [])
          .map(childObj =>
            render(childObj)
          ).join('')
      }
    </div>
  `
console.log(render(obj))
```

Comment: OK, this is a bit too clever but surprisingly also very clean. For readability I'd turn it into a proper function and get rid of all those ternaries and simply replace them with variables but otherwise the use of a string template makes the HTML structure very obvious. Well done

Comment: Thanks brother. I really appreciate your comment. I'm kinda used to use ternary, but I agree that other people that aren't used to it can find a little bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I find your approach a bit hard to understand. I think that you should use the DOM API as much as possible and, considered the potential complexity of your input object, keep your code as clean and clear as possible.

I would suggest using a recursive approach in which you process one element at a time with all the details (id, class, etc), then its children and append those before returning the new element back. This way you can also ensure that any depth is covered.

It seems pretty elegant to me :)

Hope it helps.

```js
let json = {
  id: "foo",
  rows: [
    {
      class: "blah",
      cols: [
        { class: "haha"},
        { class: "bar" },
        { class: "baz" }
      ]
    }, {
      class: "yada"
    }
  ]
}

function transform(element) {
  const { id, rows, cols, class: className } = element
  const $element = document.createElement('div')

  if ( id ) $element.setAttribute('id', id)
  if ( className ) $element.classList.add(className)
  
  let children = []
  
  if ( rows ) {
    $element.dataset.type = 'rows'
    children = rows.map(transform)
  }
  
  if ( cols ) {
    $element.dataset.type = 'cols'
    children = cols.map(transform)
  }
  
  children.forEach(function append(child) {
    $element.appendChild(child)
  })
  
  return $element
}

const $json = transform(json)
console.log($json.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes that a string will become an attribute of a div. An array will turn into several divs.

- The function only reads one level of the json at a time, creating a div + attributes.
- If it runs across an array, it will recurse itself for every array element.

```js
function appendDOM( json, element ) {
  let child = document.createElement('div');
  
  for (const property in json) {
    if( typeof json[property] === 'string' ) {
      child.setAttribute( property, json[property] );
    } else if( Array.isArray( json[property] ) ) {
     for( let i=0; i< json[property].length; i++ ) {
        appendDOM( json[property][i], child );
      }
    }
  }
  
  element.appendChild( child );
}


let json = {id: "foo",rows: [{class: "blah",cols: [{class: "haha"},{class: "bar"},{class: "baz"}]},{class: "yada", style:"background: yellow"}]}

appendDOM( json, document.getElementById('section') );
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align : center;
}
#foo::before{
  content: 'foo';
}
.blah::before{
  content: 'blah';
}
.haha::before{
  content: 'haha';
}
.bar::before{
  content: 'bar';
}
.baz::before{
  content: 'baz';
}
.yada::before{
  content: 'yada';
}
```

```html
<section id='section'></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I use HTML concat instead of elements creation.

```js
let json = {
  id: "foo",
  rows: [{
      class: "blah",
      cols: [{
        class: "haha"
      }, {
        class: "bar"
      }, {
        class: "baz"
      }]
    },
    {
      class: "yada"
    }
  ]
}

function iterateJsonToHTML(frame) {
  let html = "";
  html += '<div id = "' + frame.id + '" data-type = "rows">';
  for (let i = 0; i < frame.rows.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class = "' + frame.rows[i].class + '" data-type = "cols">';
    if (frame.rows[i].cols) {
      for (let j = 0; j < frame.rows[i].cols.length; j++) {
        html += '<div class = "' + frame.rows[i].cols[j].class + '"></div>';
      }
    }
    html += '</div>';
  }
  html += '</div>';
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;
}

iterateJsonToHTML(json);
console.log(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the answer... I think your solution presumes that only certain `div`s will have `id`s or `class`es, which is not the case.  Any div can have an id and or class.  Also it looks like this presumes rows always on the outside, and cols on the inside, which could be reversed.  Also, the structure can be arbitrarily deep (or shallow).  I've updated my question to reflect this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an academic exercise, but here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const json = {
  id: 'foo',
  rows: [
    {
      class: 'blah',
      cols: [
        { class: 'haha' },
        { class: 'bar' },
        { class: 'baz' }
      ]
    },
    { class: 'yada' }
  ]
};

const r = objectScan(['', '**'], {
  reverse: false,
  beforeFn: (state) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    state.context = [];
  },
  afterFn: (state) => {
    state.result = state.context.join('\n');
  },
  breakFn: ({ depth, value, context }) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      const properties = Object
        .entries(value)
        .map(([k, v]) => (typeof v === 'string' ? `${k} = "${v}"` : `data-type = "${k}"`));
      context.push(`${' '.repeat(depth)}<div ${properties.join(' ')}>`);
    }
  },
  filterFn: ({ depth, value, context }) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      context.push(`${' '.repeat(depth)}</div>`);
    }
  }
})(json);

console.log(r);
/* =>
<div id = "foo" data-type = "rows">
    <div class = "blah" data-type = "cols">
        <div class = "haha">
        </div>
        <div class = "bar">
        </div>
        <div class = "baz">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "yada">
    </div>
</div>
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.2"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)